# Compilation returning "Warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type"

Tags: c

**Question**

Hi, I've this function to check the current path and return the pointer of char with the path. But when I go to compile with GCC it return this two warnings. I've tried some solutions but I was can't fix it.

What is supposed to do about this warnings?

**Warnings**

```
In file included from C:\Users\Lsy\Documents\C\murtza_debug\main.c:10:0:
C:\Users\Lsy\Documents\C\murtza_debug\system/path.h:6:10: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 int *p = cwd;
          ^~~
C:\Users\Lsy\Documents\C\murtza_debug\system/path.h: In function 'get_path':
C:\Users\Lsy\Documents\C\murtza_debug\system/path.h:9:7: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     p = &cwd;
       ^
```

**Code**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

char cwd[8024];
int *p = cwd;

int* get_path() {
    p = &cwd;
    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL) {
        return p;
   }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to assign a char pointer to an *int* pointer.

Comment: You are assigning a `char` pointer to an `int` pointer, why would you expect that to work? Also, `p = &cwd;` is wrong in any case, drop the `&`.

Comment: So yes, the type `int *` is not compatible with `char *` (in the specific C-language sense of "compatible").  It's not clear to me why you're declaring `p` as an `int *` instead of a `char *` in the first place.

Comment: the next problem: What is your function returning when the `if` is not true?

Comment: @mch It's only a test function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cwd` is an array of `char` and it is converted to a pointer `char*` to the first element of the array before being assigned. Therefore, you should use `char*`, not `int*`, as the type of `p` to have it accept that and use `char*` as return type of `get_path()` to return `p`.

Also `&cwd` is an another type of pointer `char(*)[8024]` (an pointer to the array itself). It should be `cwd` to use only one type of pointer.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

char cwd[8024];
char *p = cwd;

char* get_path() {
    p = cwd;
    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL) {
        return p;
   }
}
```

Comment: I did change the function and now the GCC returns "warning: return from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types] > return p;"

Comment: @BlackCoral Sorry, the return type of `get_path()` should also be changed.